# Could not able to post data on node server

Tags: node.js

I am trying to hit http://localhost:5000/api/auth/ with post request using postman but it says "cannot post api/auth".

I am using mongo db and node js server.js

server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
var connectDB = require('./config/db');

const app = express();

//connect database
connectDB();

// initializing middleware
app.use(express.json({extended: false}));

app.get('/', (req,res) =>
 res.json({msg:'Hellow   we are here'}));

//Define Routes
app.use('api/auth', require('./routes/auth'));
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/users'));
app.use('/api/contacts', require('./routes/contacts'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log ("server running at port 5000"));
```

Here is the auth file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const {check, validationResult} = require('express-validator');
const config     = require('config');
const User = require('../models/User'); 

//@route    GET api/auth
//@desc     Get logged in user
//@access   private     

router.get('/', (req, res)=> {
    res.send('Get logged in suser');
});

//@route    POST api/auth
//@desc     Auth user and get token
//@access   public      

router.post (
    '/',
[
    check('email', 'Please enter a valid email').isEmail(),
    check('password', 'password required').exists(),
],
 async (req, res)=> {
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    if(!errors.isEmpty()){
        return res.status(400).json({errors: errors.array()});
    }   

    const {email , password} = req.body;

     try{
        let user= await User.findOne({email});
        console.log(user);

        if(!user)
        {
            return res.status(400).json({msg:"Invalid credentials"});
        }
        const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

        if(!isMatch)
        {
            return res.status(400).json({msg:"Invalid credentials"});
        }

        const payload = {
            user: { id: user.id }
                };

        jwt.sign(payload,
                config.get('jwtSecret'),
                {expiresIn: 36000},
                 (err, token) => {
                     if (err)
                     { throw err;}
                     res.send({token});
        });
     }
     catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
            res.status(500).send('server error');
     }

});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: What do those `check()` function calls do.  Please include their code.  They have to call `next()` or your route handler won't get called.

Comment: Also, you need middleware that will read the POST body for you to populate `req.body` which I don't see.

Comment: And, please don't ever write `if (err) { throw err;}` inside a plain asynchronous callback.  It does nothing useful.  It just throws back to some asynchronous infrastructure that you can't catch.  You'll just end up with no response ever being sent from the request.

Comment: Check come from express validator. i.e const {check, validationResult} = require('express-validator'); its add validation to model fields.

Comment: this is my user code and its working fine :(

Comment: What does that last comment mean or refer to?

Comment: check() function comes from library called 'express validator' basically it put contraints on data.

Answer (score 0):

There's a missing leading slash where you define the routes. It is

```
//Define Routes
app.use('api/auth', require('./routes/auth'));
```

but it should be

```
//Define Routes
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/auth'));
```